# How to create a polymorphic structure that can work for both success and error responses in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm working on a class that will get a list of strings and process them asynchronously using CompletableFutures. Each string is processed by invoking another class that will perform several operations and return a response or throw an exception if there is an error.
I would like to aggregate the responses that I get, whether they have a valid response or an exception and return them as a list to the caller. I would like the caller to be able to expect a list of `SomeResponse` and be able to interpret them using polymorphism.

However, I'm stuck on determining if this can be done using polymorphism at all, given that the fields for the success and error response are completely different. I have added some pseudo code below on one alternative I have thought of. Basically have `SomeResponse` be an interface with an `isSuccess` method. This will allow the caller to know if it's an error or not. However, the caller would still have to cast it to the correct implementation in order to get the value or the error. Is there a better way to approach this? My requirement is being able to return both a success and error response for each given request in the list. If there is an exception, we don't want to abort the entire operation.

```
public MyProcessorClass {
    private final SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

    public List<SomeResponse> process(List<String> requestList) {
        return requestList.stream().map(this::procesRequest)
               .collectors(Collect.tolist()):
    }

    private processRequest(String request) {
        CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() => {
        return new SomeSuccessResponse(someOtherClass.execute(request));
        })
        .exceptionally(e -> {
        return new SomeErrorResponse(e.getCause);
        });
        return completableFuture.get();
    }
}


public interface SomeResponse {
    boolean isSuccess();
}

public class SomeSuccessResponse implements SomeResponse {
    private final String value;
    @Getter
    private final boolean success;
    
    public SomeSuccessResponse(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.success = true;
    }
}

public class SomeErrorResponse implements SomeResponse {
    private final Throwable error;
    @Getter
    private final boolean success;

    public SomeErrorResponse(Throwable error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.success = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to question your premise and ask, are you sure using a polymorphic approach is beneficial in this case? What about a composition approach? Have a `Result<TSuccess, TFailure>` type with two fields of type `TSuccess` and `TFailure`. You can add `map` and `flatMap` to allow propagation of these two fields, much like how `Optional` is designed.

Comment: Why not looking at Optional class ? It is almost the same behavior, it is certainly a good source of inspiration for your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I think doing a composition approach is the right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the visitor pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

```java
public class Main {
    interface IResponse {
        void acceptHandler(IResponseHandler handler);
    }

    static class ResponseA implements IResponse {
        @Override
        public void acceptHandler(IResponseHandler handler) {
            handler.handle(this);
        }
    }

    static class ResponseB implements IResponse {
        @Override
        public void acceptHandler(IResponseHandler handler) {
            handler.handle(this);
        }
    }

    public interface IResponseHandler {
        void handle(ResponseA response);
        void handle(ResponseB responseB);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final IResponseHandler handler = new IResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ResponseA response) {
                System.out.println("Handle ResponseA");
            }

            @Override
            public void handle(ResponseB responseB) {
                System.out.println("Handle ResponseB");
            }
        };

        final IResponse someResponse = new ResponseA();
        someResponse.acceptHandler(handler);
    }
}
```